# QT: Como impedir alteração do conteúdo de uma QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtgui

O título da pergunta diz tudo: Como posso impedir a edição de  que uma determinada coluna de uma `QTableWidget`?

Já andei a pesquisar e penso que a solução passa pela utilização de algumas *flags*, mas não consegui chegar a uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples, e como dizes na pergunta a solução passa por utilizar *[flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum)*. Para desactivar 
o modo de edição basta fazer:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Esta alternativa tem a vantagem de não alterar o comportamento das outras *flags* apenas o da flag `Qt::ItemIsEditable`

Existem outras alternativas, como por exemplo:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Esta última faz uso do [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) para desempenhar um papel de interruptor: cada vez que é executado activa ou desactiva a edição de acordo com o estado actual.

Comment: Valeu a força! uma vez mais! :)